# How to make a proper Event Loop (or whatever it is called)?

Tags: c, infinite-loop, event-loop

*I am not a programmer or any of such, I am only someone interested in this stuff.*

I have been trying to make myself an Xbox 360 Controller Mapper, translating controller key presses into simulated keyboard key presses. Reason is that I sincerely dislike the ones out there and one has to pay to get most of them. Promise, if I ever make it good enough that I like what I've produced, I will distribute it for everyone's use for free.

Anyway, I already have made a working command-line version, yet to be as friendly as I want it to be, but still does better what most would want from it even like this. One thing I have to ask though...

As I am not a programmer or any of sorts, I lack the teachings of the experienced, except for the ones that I had from the internet. But this one thing that I couldn't find: How to make proper breathing gaps for the programme during a loop? Maybe I should first ask, is it even right to make...

```
...
while ( 1 ) {
    if ( ( GetAsyncKeyState( keyID ) & 0x8000 ) == 0x8000 ) {
        /* do this, do that */
        break;
    }
    /* breathing */
}
...
```

... a structure like the one above?

I assumed and still assume that it is, since I have no idea how else would it be possible to catch the input from the user with this C language. It would be nice to **know** than to **assume**.

If so, then my main question is; how to give the programme the room for breathing, so that it won't stress the CPU much? In other words, how should I replace the `/* breathing */` part above? I have been using `Sleep( 20~25 );`s all around, and my Task Manager simply displays 0% CPU usage all the time with that, even with `Sleep( 5 )`s actually...

Is it any bad to use Sleep? Is there any better option?

Comment: +1 for doing your research.

Comment: http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/ This is a link that most people will point you to when discussing game loops. There is also a good topic on Sleep() here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18898/is-it-safe-to-use-sleep-in-game-loop-on-windows

Comment: @JTA Read the first page of it, thanks a lot! Great link, it seems to be going to offer what I was looking for. Wanted to say thanks now, than half ~1 hour later when I finish reading it.

Comment: Not sure if I understand *exactly* what you want to do but: From the name "GetAsyncKeyState" I guess this checks if something was pressed and if not it still returns immediately. For what you want to do I think you just need to call a Function which tells the Kernel/OS to return WHEN SOMETHING HAPPENS. So then your program will simply stop until a key is pressed.

Comment: @IngoBlackman Yes, that would be great, like the way `getchar();` returns when the character \n is input. But then again, I think it wouldn't be so great, I think I rather constantly need to know whether if keys/buttons are pressed, and I think infinite loop handles it well, all it needs is a proper space for breathing. `GetAsyncKeyState( keyID );` returns immediately, with a DWORD variable hinting the state of the key from its leftmost and rightmost bits.

Comment: you should avoid calling `sleep` in an interactive application, `sleep` will prevent your application from [processing messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rather simple program demonstrating a game event loop using SDL2:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void on_render(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Window      *mainwindow = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer    *renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Event       event = { 0 };
    int             exit = 0;   // If 1, the event loop will break.

    // INITIALIZE SDL (VIDEO ONLY):
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == -1) {
        printf("SDL_Init() failed with \"%s.\"", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    // CREATE WINDOW:
    mainwindow = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Application", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(!mainwindow) {
        printf("SDL_CreateWindow() failed with \"%s.\"", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    // CREATE RENDERER:
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(mainwindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if(!renderer) {
        printf("SDL_CreateRenderer() failed with \"%s.\"", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    // MAIN LOOP:
    while(!exit) {

        // EVENT LOOP:
        if(SDL_WaitEvent(&event)) {
            switch(event.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                exit = 1;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) exit = 1;
                break;
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
                switch(event.window.event) {
                case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE:
                    exit = 1;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            default: break;
            }
        }

        // RENDER SCREEN:
        on_render(mainwindow, renderer);

        // SWAP BUFFERS TO DISPLAY:
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    // CLEAN-UP:
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(mainwindow);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

void on_render(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    int rect_width = 300, rect_height = 300;
    SDL_Rect window_rect = { 0 };

    // CLEAR THE SCREEN WITH A BLUE COLOR:
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    // DRAW A RECTANGLE:
    SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &window_rect.w, &window_rect.h);

    SDL_Rect draw_rect = {
        (window_rect.x + (window_rect.w / 2) - (rect_width / 2)) - 1,
        (window_rect.y + (window_rect.h / 2) - (rect_height / 2)) - 1,
        rect_width + 2,
        rect_height + 2
    };

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &draw_rect);
}
```

*Credit: `Xeek` on `freenode` wrote this for me when I went over to ask about event loops.*

Now, if you aren't writing a game, perhaps you do not want to consume all of the CPU time, in which case a simple

```
usleep (1);
```

right before the end of the outermost `while` loop should cut it.

Using your code, here is an example (which happens to depend on having a POSIXy system (Linux, OSX, etc.):

```
// includes and defines
#include <unistd.h>     // usleep() is defined here
...

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    // setup and stuff
    ...

    int exit = 0;
    while (!exit) {
        if ((GetAsyncKeyState(keyID) & 0x8000) == 0x8000) {
            // handle the input or whatever
            ...
        }

        // check if it is time to exit yet
        if (some exit condition) {
            exit = 1;
        }

        usleep (100);   // sleep for 100 us
    }

    // cleanup
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

### EDIT:

us is microseconds, not milliseconds. Silly me :)

Comment: `usleep (1);` rather sleeps for 1 microsecond (1 μs) than 1 millisecond (1 ms), since `u` in `usleep` is `u` only because it is the most similar ASCII character to `μ`. Thanks for the help

Comment: Oh, yeah, my bad. On one hand, you'll have instantaneous response, but on the other hand, you'll slow down any other applications that are running.